# Dependency Injection - adding Customer object causing test to fail

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, repository

I have used Constructor injection on a repository for class, I have noticed the following works:

```
    public CreateInvoiceResult CreateInvoice(string Code, int qty, string Name)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Code) || qty <= 0 || repository.GetByName(Name).ID <= 0)
        {
            return new CreateInvoiceResult(false);
        }
```

However changing to the following code (adding in 'Customer cust') causes test to fail?

```
 public CreateInvoiceResult CreateInvoice(string stockCode, int quantity, string customerName)
 {
     Customer cust = repository.GetByName(Name);

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Code) || qty <= 0 || cust.ID <= 0)
     {
         return new CreateInvoiceResult(false);
     }
```

Example Test:

Please can you explain why this is happening and how I can correct?

EDIT: Have updated test using Moq, to use correct repository:

```
[TestClass]
public class MockCustomerRepositoryDBTests
{
    public MockCustomerRepositoryDBTests()
    {
        IList<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer { ID = 1, Name = "Jim Smith",
                Address = "14 Main Road"},
            new Customer { ID = 2, Name = "Alex Smith",
                Address = "78 Avanue"},
            new Customer { ID = 3, Name = "Paul Brown",
                Address = "1 Main Road"}
        };

        // Mock the CustomerRepositoryDB Repository using Moq
        Mock<ICustomerRepository> mockCustomerRepository = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();

        // Return a customer by Name
        mockCustomerRepository.Setup(mr => mr.GetByName(
            It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string s) => customers.Where(
            x => x.Name == s).Single());

        // Complete the setup of the Mock Customer Repository
        this.MockCustomerRepository = mockCustomerRepository.Object;
    }

    public readonly ICustomerRepository MockCustomerRepository;

    [TestMethod]
    public void stockCodeIsNullOrEmpty()
    {
        //Arrange
        var x = new InvoiceController(MockCustomerRepository);

        //Act
        bool result = x.CreateInvoice("", 1, "test").Success;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(result, false);
    }
```

Getting 'System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements'

Comment: you should ask a separate question about your moq.

Comment: No need to delete all of the original question :). I'll put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your call to

```
Customer _Customer = repository.GetByName(customerName);
```

is probably failing with some exception.

If you look at your class you only initialize you repository object in this constructor:

```
public PartInvoiceController(ICustomerRepository custRepo)
{
    this.repository = custRepo;
}
```

however you provide a default constructor which you call in the test:

```
//Arrange
var x = new PartInvoiceController();
```

So your repository is never initialised and so you will get a null reference exception.

Why didn't it fail before?

When it was part of the if statement it didn't matter as it was never executed, because the `string.IsNullOrEmpty(stockCode)` is true and the other conditions are combined using the [conditional-or operator (||)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx), which will short-circuit evaluating conditions if it can tell that the condition is going to be true or false even if all conditions are not evaluated.

The if statement was entered because of this and the other conditions were never evaluated, so the repository being null was code that was never executed.

To correct it you need to either provide a repository to use in the test (a stub or a mock), or create a default repository in the default constructor, or revert to the original code (as long as you don't care about the repository not being initialised in this test).

change your test like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void stockCodeIsNullOrEmpty()
{
    ICustomerRepository testRepository = //create a test repository here
    //Arrange
    var x = new PartInvoiceController(testRespository);

    //Act
    bool result = x.CreatePartInvoice("", 1, "test").Success;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(result, false);
}
```

EDIT

really you should ask another question about your mock problems, but basically you are looking for a user with the name "test" but none of your users in the mock repository have that name

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think it is failing with "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." - how would I correct?

Comment: I have provided information on how to correct it at the end of the answer. you need to provide a repository in the test, otherwise what repository will the class use to get the user from?

Comment: No problem. if you found an answer helpful then you should upvote it using the up arrow at the top left of the answer. If an answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the tick mark under the voting arrows. See [Why Vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), and consider taking [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to familiarise yourself with how the site works. Good site citizens generally ask better questions and get better answers.

Comment: OK need 15 rep to upvote - still have issue though will edit above.

Comment: No problem. And welcome to stackoverflow, you did a pretty good job of asking for your first question. If you had asked a separate question though, you could have got that one upvoted as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer _Customer = repository.GetByName(customerName);
```

Member variable "repository" is not initialized before using. You should use the other constructor  of class PartInvoiceController.